# jQuery event handlers stop working upon leaving view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm implementing a Rails audio_tag along with Javascript:

```
<%= audio_tag current_word.sound, autoplay: true, class: "audio-play" %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg", id="audioButton">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
    });
});
```

This works well when I either go into the page after a site refresh or when reloading the page. Otherwise, if I click away and come back from the menu, there will be an initial autoplay, and the button will show but won't work when clicked. How can I keep the jQuery loading in this context?

Comment: Are you sure about the correct useage of **return** here? Would you remove it and test again?

Comment: I tried removing it and got the same result.

Comment: Aslo try Play with capital P if you are using chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly coming up against TurboLinks, which is bypassing your `jQuery(document).ready` callback.

If you just want to turn off TurboLinks (because while it's blazingly fast, it does have some annoying effects), all you have to do is edit your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file and remove this line:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

This will disable TurboLinks in your application, and your existing code should work just fine.

However, if you want to keep using TurboLinks in your application, you need to also handle special events for when the page is dynamically updated.  The events are "page:load" and "page:restore", and should be handled in the same way as your `jQuery(document).ready` callback.

I typically include all of these in a small script at the bottom of my HTML page `<body>`, like so:

```
<body>
  <!-- important body stuff -->
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(onThisPageReady);
  jQuery(document).on('page:load', onThisPageReady);
  jQuery(document).on('page:restore', onThisPageReady);
  </script>
</body>
```

In the Javascript (or CoffeeScript) source, you can include:

```
function onThisPageReady() {
    $("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
    });
}
```

Now, you have page initialization for all occasions.  TurboLinks offers a few more events that you can register for, if you choose, and the complete list is found here: [TurboLinks Events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events).  If you're starting a Rails 5 app, the version of TurboLinks is *new*, and has a totally different set of events to register, which you can find in the [TurboLinks 5 Full List of Events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events).

Answer (score 3):

If elements change dynamically, use event delegation.

Instead of:

```
$("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
```

Use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#audioButton", function() {
```

Comment: Oh no, I'm confused. You right my answer is'nt right. So I will delete it right now! Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it directly, without document.ready

```
$("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
    $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
    return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
  });
```